# Load OWL schema into triple-store like Fuskei/TDB?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena, owl, triplestore

I have a beautiful OWL schema that I wrote that I would like to actually load into a triple-store and then add data to so that I can query it.  But I'm a bit clueless about how to do that.

You see, I have Fuseki/TDB, solely because Jena comes with them and I like the Jena APIs.  But I have no idea how to actually put this schema into a triple-store.  Does one even load a schema like one does with traditional databases?  I don't know.

I have Fuseki/TDB running, and followed [the “getting started” tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/), but that tutorial deals with loading data into the default graph, and I don't know how to move any further.  Help?  Clues?  Should I go with a different triple-store setup with actual detailed how-to documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schemas are data.  You can load them as you would for data.

If you want inference based on the schema, you don't need to load it - you need to write a Fuseki configuration that uses your schema with a inference engine like Jena rules.

Comment: How would I write a Fuskei configuration that uses my schema?   Am I supposed to use Assemblers?  (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/assembler.html) can you point me to an example?  I find myself awash in uncertainty.