# How I can write a Fuseki configuration that uses my schema

Tags: jena, rdfs, triplestore, tdb, fuseki

I have a question.

I have two files: a Model file with data and a OntModel with schema.
I have stored these files ina  Jena TDB as described in this post: [How I can use Fuseki with Jena TDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798024/how-i-can-use-fuseki-with-jena-tdb/24798896#24798896)

My question is: is it correct to store my schema in Jena TDB?
I have readed a similar question in this post: [Load OWL schema into triple-store like Fuskei/TDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038660/load-owl-schema-into-triple-store-like-fuskei-tdb)

where it's written that

> "Schemas are data. You can load them as you would for data. If you
>   want inference based on the schema, you don't need to load it - you
>   need to write a Fuseki configuration that uses your schema with a
>   inference engine like Jena rules."

How I can write a Fuseki configuration that uses my schema with a inference engine like Jena rules?

Comment: There's a [Fuseki Configuration File](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/#fuseki-configuration-file) section in the documentation, and it mentions that you can use inference models.  Then you'll need to get into the assembler initialization, for which see [Jena assembler quickstart](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/assembler/index.html).  There's a bit in there about **How can I specify … an inference model?**  Once you've gone through that documentation, if you're still having problems, it will be easier to ask a more specific question about your configuration file.

Comment: At the moment, I think this is probably too broad, since there are lots of ways that you could "write a Fuseki configuration that uses [your] schema with a inference engine like Jena rules."